# Is the following answer a mistake?

Tags: functions

$A=x\in\Bbb R: x>2$ and $B=x\in\Bbb R: x>0$

let $f: A \mapsto B $ be the function $f:x \mapsto \frac{2x-3}{x-2}$

The question asked to show that f is one to one, and for the answer it said it wasnt but from my working out it doesnt seem wrong.

This was taken from part a of the question asking to find $p,q \in \Bbb R$ such that $f(x) = \frac{p}{x-2}+q$
\begin{align}
& =\frac{1}{x-2}+2\\
& \frac{1}{a-2}+2=\frac{1}{a-2}+2\\
& \frac{1}{a-2}=\frac{1}{a-2}\\
& b-2=a-2\\
& b=a\\
\end{align}

also I tried doing it with the original $f(x)$

\begin{align}
& \frac{2a-3}{a-2}=\frac{2b-3}{b-2}\\
& 2a-3(b-2)=2b-3(a-2)\\
& 2ab-4a-3b+6=2ab-4b-3a+6\\
& 2ab-a=2ab-b \\
& a(2b-1) = b(2a-1)\\
\end{align}
Which could be interpreted as a=b ? hence proving function is one to one

Comment: It is one to one. But it is not onto (surjective). There is no $x$ such that $f(x)=2$

Comment: well havent tested for surjective yet but the book says it is not one to one so I am a bit confused. @marwalix

Comment: The book is wrong. A typo may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to work backwards. That is try to finf if inverse of the function exists; that will  provide answer for both surjectivity and 1-1. 
Suppose for  a specific number $y$, we have an inverse image.

Then $y\displaystyle=\frac{2x-3}{x-2}$. This means $(2x-3)=y(x-2)$. From this we are forced to conclude that $x=\displaystyle\frac{3-2y}{2-y}$. Only trouble is to jusify dividing by $2-y$; this is possible only for $y\ne 2$. SO it is not surjective as $2$ is missing in the image of $f$. For all others inverse image is unique. So it is 1-1.